# Publish Spring MVC Metrics To Multiple Monitoring System Simultaneously Using Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, datadog, micrometer

I have a use case wherein I want to publish my spring boot API metrics to Datadog & CloudWatch simultaneously.

I have added the below dependencies to my pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-statsd</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-cloudwatch</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Main Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    @Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
      return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("my-tag", "my-common-tag");
    }
}
```

I have added all required properties in the `application. properties` as well.

I can see metrics are being published to both Datadog & CloudWatch with default metrics name `http.server.request`
But I want the metrics name for Datadog to be different & for this, I have added the below property.

`management.metrics.web.server.requests-metric-name = i.want.to.be.different`

But this is changing the name for both CloudWatch & Datadog.

My question is, how can I change the default metrics name for Datadog only or keep words different for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micrometer uses `MeterFilter`s registered with a `MeterRegistry` to modified the meters that are registered. The modifications include the ability to map a meter's ID to something different.

In Spring Boot, you can use a `MeterRegistryCustomizer` bean to add a `MeterFilter` to a registry. You can use generics to work with a registry of a specific type, for example `MeterRegistryCustomizer<DatadogMeterRegistry>` for a customizer that is only interested in customizing the Datadog registry.

Putting this together, you can map the ID of the `http.server.request` meter to `i.want.to.be.different` using the following bean:

```java
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<DatadogMeterRegistry> datadogMeterIdCustomizer() {
    return (registry) -> registry.config().meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {

        @Override
        public Id map(Id id) {
            if ("http.server.request".equals(id.getName())) {
                return id.withName("i.want.to.be.different");
            }
            return id;
        }

    });
}
```